# error using the 'digest' package in R

Tags: r, package, digest

I recently had some problems installing and using the package "digest" in R-3.4.3, which I used previously in R-3.4.1  with no problem. Below are the messages I received from R.

```
install.packages("digest", dependencies = TRUE)
trying URL 'https://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/digest_0.6.15.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 175238 bytes (171 KB)
downloaded 171 KB

package ‘digest’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

The downloaded binary packages are in
        C:\Users\weizha\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpwhNFrq\downloaded_packages

```
library(digest) 

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘digest’ in FUN(X[[i]], ...): 
no such symbol digest in package E:/R 3.4.3/library/digest/libs/x64/digest.dll
```

Previously I used `install.packages(devtools)` in R-3.4.1 which installs "digest" as well, and it all worked fine. Recently work upgraded our operating system to windows 10 (from 7) and installed R-3.4.3 for us, and I couldn't get devtools to work anymore, I figured out it's because digest is not working as has been shown above. I've read everything I can find online, but I have no clue how to fix this.

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "E:/R-3.4.3/library"
> install.packages("digest", lib="E:/R-3.4.3/library")
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
trying URL 'https://cran.csiro.au/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/digest_0.6.15.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 175238 bytes (171 KB)
downloaded 171 KB

package ‘digest’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
        C:\Users\weizha\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCQY8o1\downloaded_packages
> library(digest)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘digest’ in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
 no such symbol digest in package E:/R-3.4.3/library/digest/libs/x64/digest.dll
> library("digest", lib.loc="E:/R-3.4.3/library")
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘digest’ in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
 no such symbol digest in package E:/R-3.4.3/library/digest/libs/x64/digest.dll


> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 14393)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.3 tools_3.4.3   
>
```

---

```
> setwd('E:/R-3.4.3')
> install.packages("digest", type="source")
trying URL 'https://cran.csiro.au/src/contrib/digest_0.6.15.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 122095 bytes (119 KB)
downloaded 119 KB

* installing *source* package 'digest' ...
** package 'digest' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
Warning: running command 'make -f "E:/R-34~1.3/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "E:/R-34~1.3/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="digest.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="aes.o crc32.o digest.o init.o md5.o pmurhash.o raes.o sha1.o sha2.o sha256.o xxhash.o"' had status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'digest'
* removing 'E:/R-3.4.3/library/digest'
In R CMD INSTALL

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘C:\Users\weizha\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCQY8o1\downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: running command '"E:/R-3.4.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "E:\R-3.4.3\library" C:\Users\weizha\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCQY8o1/downloaded_packages/digest_0.6.15.tar.gz' had status 1 
2: In install.packages("digest", type = "source") :
  installation of package ‘digest’ had non-zero exit status
```

---

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "E:/R-3.4.3/library"
> install.packages("digest", type="binary")
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
trying URL 'https://cran.csiro.au/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/digest_0.6.15.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 175238 bytes (171 KB)
downloaded 171 KB

package ‘digest’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
        C:\Users\weizha\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0UupHr\downloaded_packages
> library(digest)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘digest’ in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
 no such symbol digest in package E:/R-3.4.3/library/digest/libs/x64/digest.dll
```

When I manually download the package from CRAN, this is what I received from R

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "E:/R-3.4.3/library"
> library(digest)
Error: package ‘digest’ was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘digest’ was built under R version 3.5.0 
>
```

Comment: Can you add your `sessionInfo()` and verify that the library path returned in the error is definitely the place where `digest` was installed? I'd also try removing and reinstalling to see if you get the same error.

Comment: Thank you Esther for your reply. I've tried manually removing digest and reinstalling it again, I've also verified the library path, it's still not working. I edited my original question to include he library path and session info.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to install and load fine on the same version/system. What if you remove and install from source, `install.packages("digest", type="source")` ?

Comment: Thanks Esther. I tried what you suggested and received a new error message as shown in the edited question :(

Comment: Sorry I actually told you the wrong thing for windows, try running it with `type=binary` and/or manually downloading and unzipping the package into your library from the [CRAN website](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/digest/index.html). I assume all your other packages in the library except `devtools` are loading fine?

Comment: Thanks Esther. I tried both options. The first option gave me the same error message as before. I then downloaded the r-release for windows: digest 0.6.15.zip from the CRAN website, and manually installed digest in my library, this time I received a different error message as shown in the question above...

Comment: Which binary version did you pick? you might need to pick the r-oldrelease one since you're using the older version of R.

Comment: I tried all 3 versions. The first two gave me the last error message I posted above, and the r-oldrelease gave me the same error message I had from the beginning... very frustrating :(

Comment: Hi Esther, the issue has been resolved. Getting the latest version of R and Rtools fixed it. Thanks a lot for all your suggestions.